# Can Google Access a Password-Protected Subdomain?

Tags: .htaccess

I added the following to `.htaccess` in the subdomain folder:

```
AuthName "beta server"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/.htpasswd
Require user username
```

I just want to double check that this will prevent google (and other bots) from crawling the content, so I don't have to deal with duplicate content issues.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options available for this. You can easily implement them all as they wont conflict and that way you might be a little bit more reassured.

The first is blocking bad bots, the viewing of the .htaccess file and prevent directory listings

```
            //Block bad bots
            RewriteEngine On 
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^eCatch [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EirGrabber [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailWolf [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Express\ WebPictures [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EyeNetIE [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetRight [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetWeb! [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go!Zilla [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go-Ahead-Got-It [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GrabNet [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Grafula [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^HMView [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} HTTrack [NC,OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Stripper [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Sucker [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Indy\ Library [NC,OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InterGET [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Internet\ Ninja [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JetCar [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JOC\ Web\ Spider [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^larbin [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LeechFTP [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mass\ Downloader [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MIDown\ tool [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mister\ PiX [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Navroad [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NearSite [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetAnts [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetSpider [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Net\ Vampire [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetZIP [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Octopus [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Explorer [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Navigator [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PageGrabber [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Papa\ Foto [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pavuk [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pcBrowser [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^RealDownload [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ReGet [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SiteSnagger [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SmartDownload [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperBot [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperHTTP [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Surfbot [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^tAkeOut [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Teleport\ Pro [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^VoidEYE [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Image\ Collector [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Sucker [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebAuto [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebCopier [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebFetch [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebGo\ IS [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebLeacher [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebReaper [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebSauger [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ eXtractor [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ Quester [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebStripper [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebWhacker [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus
            RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]

            //Prevent viewing of .htaccess file
            <Files .htaccess>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
            </Files>

            //Prevent directory listings
            Options All -Indexes
```

This was taken from this free .htaccess generator: http://www.htaccessredirect.net/index.php

The next thing would be to create a robots.txt file. Google have a great page for this:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449?hl=en

and then the third would also be to include the password protection that you have already.

It would be awesome for other people to post their suggestions, ideas and criticism. We could make this page THE page for directory protection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this does prevent Google from indexing your content.

Google itself recommends this as "the simplest and most effective way" to block URLs: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93708